# Android: CountDownTimer equivalent in Flutter SDK

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have a custom `View` in Android Studio that updates every x milliseconds using a custom animation. I'm now trying to implement this behaviour in Dart. This is how the animation is implemented in Android Java. (It represents only the animation logic and does nothing else)

```
public class ItemAnim extends CountDownTimer {

    public ItemAnim(long millisInFuture, long countdownInterval){
       super(millisInFuture, countdownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {    
        // do anim stuff like setting a rotation angle variable etc...
        // listener.animate(...) code
    }
}
```

I'm now looking for a very similar class in Dart/Flutter SDK.

i.e. a class that calls `onTick(millisUntilFinished)` every `countdownInterval` milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

> Timer.periodic(duration, callback)

It will repeat the task until cancelled

Example

```
var timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t){
      //your code here
    });
```

To cancel use

> timer.cancel();